# Angular2 material design dropdowns in loop

Tags: angular, material-design, dropdown, angular-material2

I am looping through an array (serviceOptions) and for each option I have a drop-down. The drop is auto complete. When I select some option in any drop down it is shown in  of all the drop downs. The issue is due to [mdAutocomplete]="package". I need to change this "package" here to something dynamic and like wise at #package="mdAutocomplete" in .
Any help?

```
<label *ngFor="let service of serviceOptions">
    {{service.serviceName}}
    <br/>
    <md-input-container class="autoCompolete">
      <input mdInput placeholder="Select Package" [mdAutocomplete]="package" [formControl]="packageCtrl" formControlName="packageName" [(ngModel)]="currentpackage" size="30">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-autocomplete #package="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayPackage">
        <md-option (onSelectionChange)="packageSelection($event, package)" [value]="package" *ngFor="let package of (reactivePackages | async)">
          {{ package.packageName }}
          {{package.serviceId}}
          {{service.serviceId}}
        </md-option>
    </md-autocomplete>
    <br />
  </label>
```

Comment: I don't think using the same autocomplete is the issue here. I created this example to confirm that 

https://plnkr.co/edit/PHJkJpkgOXLTEWpDI3eX?p=preview

You can actually take the autocomplete outside of `ngFor` loop. I think the issue is all the `input` fields have the same `formControl` and `ngModel`. Because of that, when you are selecting any of them, all of them getting set as they are all binded to that same `[(ngModel)]="currentpackage"`

Comment: @Nehal is there any solution in your mind by which this can be handled?

Comment: I couldn't offer a solution in the first place cause I don't know how `serviceOptions` looks like, or what value you are trying to set by using autocomplete. If you can provide that, and some explanation what value you are trying to update, then I might be able to find a solution.